# What is $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac1{n(n+x)}$ equal to?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was wondering how we could calculate the sum $S(x)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac1{n(n+x)}$ for any real $x$.

I've noted the following properties regarding the sum (which may or may not be useful to actually finding $S(x)$):

- We have the identity $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac1{n(n+x)}=\frac1x\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac1{n}-\frac1{n+x}$ for $x\neq0$. If we rearrange the terms in the sum, we find that for $x\in\mathbb{Z}_+$, $S(x)=\frac{H_x}{x}$, where $H_x$ is the [xth harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number). This means $S(x)\sim\frac{\ln x}x$ for positive $x$.
- The case $x=0$ is  the Basel Problem, so we know $S(0)=\frac{\pi^2}6$.
- For $x\in\mathbb{Z}_-$, there is an $n$ such that $n+x=0$ and $\frac1{n(n+x)}=\pm\infty$. So $S(x)=\pm\infty$ for $x\in\mathbb{Z}_-$.
- $S'(x)=-\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac1{n(n+x)^2}$. As $\frac1{n(n+x)^2}$ is negative, this means that (ignoring discontinuities) $S(x)$ is strictly decreasing.

However, I have no idea how to actually get a closed form of $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac1{n(n+x)}$ for non-integer $x$. How could I calculate this sum?

Comment: Could be expressed in terms of the di-gamma function, as I see it.

Comment: Note that $H_x$ is only defined for positive integer values. But the di-gamma function can be treated as an analytic continuation of this. and we have $$ψ\left(x+1\right)=H_{x}-γ$$
Check out the wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function

Comment: @Mourad I could replace $H_x$ with $\psi(x+1)+\gamma$, but how would I prove that this is the correct answer for non-integer $x$?

Comment: According to Wikipedia $\psi(x+1)+\gamma=\int^1_0\frac{1-t^x}{1-t}dt$, maybe that could be useful.

Comment: It involves taking this limit-definition of the gamma function $$Γ\left(x+1\right)=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{n!n^{x}}{\left(x+1\right)\left(x+2\right)..\left(x+n\right)}$$
And differentiating it logarithmic ally.
From there, you'll reach your desired sum.

Comment: Not sure if that helps, but using Euler's partial fraction series for the cotangent function, you can get something like $S(x)+S(-x)=\frac 1 {x^2}-\frac {\pi}{x}\cot(\pi x)$ for $x$ not an integer.

Comment: @Mourad Thanks for the hint, I was able to figure out how to show $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac1{n(n+x)}=\frac{\psi(x+1)+\gamma}{x}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sum is$$\frac1x\sum_{n\ge1}\int_0^1t^{n-1}(1-t^x)dt=\frac1x\int_0^1\frac{1-t^x}{1-t}dt=\frac{H_x}{x}.$$With the integral-based definition of continuous Harmonic numbers, this is valid even for $x\in\Bbb R^+\setminus\Bbb N$.

Answer (score 2):

One of the definitions of the gamma function is that

$$\Gamma(x+1)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!x^n}{(x+1)(x+2)\cdots(x+n)}$$
Working from here,
$$\ln(\Gamma(x+1))=\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln(n!)+x\ln n-\ln(x+1)-\ln(x+2)-\cdots-\ln(x+n)$$
$$\frac d{dx}\ln(\Gamma(x+1))=\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln n-\frac1{x+1}-\frac1{x+2}-\cdots-\frac1{x+n}$$
$$\psi(x+1)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln n-\sum^n_{i=1}\frac1{x+i}$$
$$\psi(x+1)=\lim_{n\to\infty}H_n+\left(\ln n-H_n\right)-\sum^n_{i=1}\frac1{x+i}$$
$$\psi(x+1)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum^n_{i=1}\frac1{i}+\left(\ln n-\ln n-\gamma-O\left(\frac1n\right)\right)-\sum^n_{i=1}\frac1{x+i}$$
$$\psi(x+1)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum^n_{i=1}\left[\frac1{i}-\frac1{x+i}\right]-\gamma-O\left(\frac1n\right)$$
$$\psi(x+1)=\sum^\infty_{i=1}\left[\frac1{i}-\frac1{x+i}\right]-\gamma$$
$$\sum^\infty_{i=1}\left[\frac1{i}-\frac1{x+i}\right]=\psi(x+1)+\gamma$$
$$\frac1x\sum^\infty_{i=1}\left[\frac1{i}-\frac1{x+i}\right]=\frac{\psi(x+1)+\gamma}x$$
$$\sum^\infty_{i=1}\frac1{i(i+x)}=\frac{\psi(x+1)+\gamma}x$$

Thus $$S(x)=\frac{\psi(x+1)+\gamma}x$$

(Credit to @Mourad for providing hints for me)

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote it
$$S_p=\frac 1x \sum_{n=1}^p\left(\frac{1}{n }-\frac{1}{n+x} \right)=\frac 1x\left(H_p +H_x-H_{p+x}\right)$$

Using the asymptotics of harmonic numbers
$$S_p=\frac{H_x}{x}-\frac{1}{p}+\frac{x+1}{2
   p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$

Comment: I wasn't looking for $\sum^p_{n=1}\frac1{n(n+x)}$ for finite $p$. I was looking at the infinite sum for non-integer $x$, and I've already figured out what it equals to (see my answer).

Comment: @Kyky. I know that. I made the sum up to $p$, used asymptotics and made $p\to \infty$. This is a classic procedure. Moreover, my limit is shorter than your even if identical. Cheers :-)

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification.