# What is $\sum^\infty_{i=1}\frac1{\prod^n_{j=0}i+jx}=\sum^\infty_{i=0}\frac1{i(i+x)(i+2x)\cdots(i+nx)}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification, products

(This is a follow up to [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3821901/what-is-sum-infty-n-1-frac1nnx-equal-to). Note that the linked question is about the case $n=1$.)

What is $$\sum^\infty_{i=1}\frac1{\prod^n_{j=0}i+jx}=\sum^\infty_{i=1}\frac1{i(i+x)(i+2x)\cdots(i+nx)}$$

My attempt:

I tried doing something similar to what J.G. did, by rewriting the sum as an integral.

We first note that $\int^1_0 t^{n-1}dt=\frac{t^n}{n}\big|^1_0=\frac{1^n-0^n}{n}=\frac 1n$. Then:

$$\sum^\infty_{i=1}\frac1{\prod^n_{j=0}i+jx}$$
$$=\sum^\infty_{i=1}\prod^n_{j=0}\frac1{i+jx}$$
$$=\sum^\infty_{i=1}\prod^n_{j=0}\int^1_0 t^{i+jx-1}dt$$
$$=\int^1_0 \prod^n_{j=0}t^{jx}\sum^\infty_{i=1}t^{i-1}dt$$
$$=\int^1_0t^{x\sum^n_{j=0}j}\frac{1}{1-t}dt$$
$$=\int^1_0\frac{t^{\frac{xn(n+1)}2}}{1-t}dt$$

However, when I plug in $n=1$, this gives me $$\int^1_0\frac{t^x}{1-t}dt$$

What I should have gotten is $\frac1x\int^1_0\frac{1-t^x}{1-t}dt$, which means I did something wrong. Where is my mistake, and how should I have done it? (The transition from $=\sum^\infty_{i=0}\prod^n_{j=0}\int^1_0 t^{i+jx-1}dt$ to $=\int^1_0 \prod^n_{j=0}t^{jx}\sum^\infty_{i=0}t^{i-1}dt$ <s>seems questionable</s> is incorrect as GEdgar pointed out it is incorrect to swap the product and sum or integral signs.)

Comment: You identified the problematic step correctly.

Comment: You can (often) interchange $\sum$ and $\int$.  But you can (almost) never interchange $\prod$ and $\int$.

Comment: @GEdgar what about interchanging $\prod$ and $\sum$?

Comment: That is also disallowed.  Try it yourself: is $(1+2)*(3+4) = (1*3)+(2*4)$?

Comment: Huh. So what should I do after $\sum^\infty_{i=1}\prod^n_{j=0}\int^1_0 t^{i+jx-1}dt$? Perhaps I should rewrite $\prod^n_{j=0}\frac1{i+jx}$ as $\exp\left(\sum^n_{j=0}\log\left(\frac1{i+jx}\right)\right)$?

Comment: Are you saying the answer doesn’t depend on $n$?

Comment: Where did I say that? I only substituted $n=1$ to verify my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general we have
$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i (i+a_1)\cdots(i+a_n)}=(-1)^{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{ H_{a_k}}{a_k \prod_{1\le j\le n,j \not= k}(a_k-a_j)}$
due to partial fraction expansion of LHS's summand and that $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{(a+n) (b+n)}=\frac{H_a-H_b}{a-b}$, thus OP's sum equals
$$(-1)^{n-1}x^{-n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{ H_{kx}}{k \prod_{1\le j\le n,j \not= k}(k-j)}$$

Comment: $\prod_{1\le j\le n,j \not= k}(k-j)=(k-1)(k-2)\cdots(2)(1)(-1)(-2)\cdots(k-n)=(k-1)!(-1)^{n-k}(n-k)!$, so the expression simplifies to $(-1)^{n-1}x^{-n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{ H_{kx}}{k (k-1)!(-1)^{n-k}(n-k)!}=(-1)^{n-1}x^{-n}\sum_{k=1}^n H_{kx}(-1)^{n-k}\frac{1}{k!(n-k)!}=(-1)^{n-1}x^{-n}\sum_{k=1}^n H_{kx}(-1)^{n-k}\frac{\binom nk}{n!}=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^{-n}}{n!}\sum_{k=1}^n H_{kx}(-1)^{n-k}\binom nk$. I couldn't simplify it further.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the interchange is not valid as products are involved.
Also at $i=0$ there is a divergence thus we will ignore $i=0$

You can start by using partial fraction on the product to get:
$$\prod^n_{k=0}\frac{1\:}{m+kx\:}= \frac{a_0}{m} +\sum _{k=1}^n\frac{a_k}{m+kx}$$
To determine $a_j :j \not=0 $ we integrate both sides around circular contour centred at $\frac{-m}  {j}$ with radius $\xi$ as $\xi\rightarrow 0$
Therefore:
$$\lim _{\xi \to 0}\int _0^{2\pi }i\xi \:e^{i\theta \:}d\theta \:\prod ^n_{k=0}\frac{1}{m+k\left(-\frac{m}{j}+\xi \:e^{i\theta \:}\right)\:}=\frac{2i\pi a_j}{j}$$
$$\frac{2i\pi a_j}{j}=\lim _{\xi \to 0}\int _0^{2\pi }i\xi \:e^{i\theta \:}d\theta\:\prod ^n_{k=0}\frac{1}{m+k\left(-\frac{m}{j}+\xi \:e^{i\theta \:}\right)\:}$$
$$\frac{2i\pi a_j}{j}=\lim _{\xi \to 0}\int _0^{2\pi }id\theta\:\prod ^n_{k=0\\ k\not=j\ 
}\frac{1}{m+k\left(-\frac{m}{j}+\xi \:e^{i\theta \:}\right)\:}$$
Therefore:
$$a_j=j\prod ^n_{k=0\\ k\not=j\ 
}\frac{j}{mj-km}=j\:\left(\frac{j}{m}\right)^n\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-j}}{j!\left(n-j\right)!}$$
Now plugging everything in sum we get:
$$\sum _{m=1}^{\infty }\left(\sum _{j=0}^nj\left(\left(\frac{j}{m}\right)^n\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-j}}{n!}\begin{pmatrix}n\\ j\end{pmatrix}\right)\frac{1}{m+jx}\right)=S$$
Interchaging order of summation and use $$\int _0^1\:u^{m+xj-1}du=\frac{1}{m+xj}$$ We get:
$$S=\sum _{j=0}^n j\left(\frac{j^n\left(-1\right)^{n-j}}{n!}\begin{pmatrix}n\\ \:\:j\end{pmatrix}\right)\int _0^1\:\sum _{m=1}^{\infty }\left(\frac{u^m}{m^n}\right)\frac{u^{jx}}{u}\:\:du$$
$$S=\sum _{j=0}^n j\left(\frac{j^n\left(-1\right)^{n-j}}{n!}\begin{pmatrix}n\\ \:j\end{pmatrix}\right)\int _0^1 \text{Li}_n\left(u\right)\frac{u^{jx}}{u}\:\:du$$
This is progress so far, the final task is to evaluate sum then solve integral and we will be done. Unfortunatly I can't find closed form of series in meantime . When I solve it I'll update you.

**Update:**

We can write sum $S$ as :
$$\frac{d^{n+1}}{dx^{n+1}}\left(\int _0^1\:\sum _{j=0}^n \:\left(\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-j}u^{jx}}{n!}\begin{pmatrix}n\\ \:j\end{pmatrix}\right)\frac{\text{Li}_n\left(u\right)}{u\:\ln ^{n+1}\left(u\right)}\:\:du\right)\:=\frac{d^{n+1}}{dx^{n+1}}\left(\int _0^1\frac{1}{n!}\:\left(u^x-1\right)^n\frac{\text{Li}_n\left(u\right)}{u\left(\ln \left(u\right)\right)^{n+1}}\:\:du\right)\:$$

Comment: Yes I realised that $i=0$ would diverge and meant $i=1$.

Comment: I'd like to point out $\frac{d^{n+1}}{dx^{n+1}}\left[\int _0^1\frac{1}{n!}\left(u^x-1\right)^n\frac{\text{Li}_n\left(u\right)}{u\left(\ln \left(u\right)\right)^{n+1}}du\right]=\int _0^1\frac{\partial^{n+1}}{\partial x^{n+1}}\left[\frac{1}{n!}\left(u^x-1\right)^n\frac{\text{Li}_n\left(u\right)}{u\left(\ln \left(u\right)\right)^{n+1}}\right]du=\int _0^1\frac{1}{n!}\frac{\text{Li}_n\left(u\right)}{u\left(\ln \left(u\right)\right)^{n+1}}\frac{\partial^{n+1}}{\partial x^{n+1}}\left[\left(u^x-1\right)^n\right]du$ by Leibniz Integral Rule.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know what $\frac{\partial^{n+1}}{\partial x^{n+1}}\left[\left(u^x-1\right)^n\right]$ is, but after messing with it I believe it is equal to $\frac{\ln^{n+1}(u)}{n!}P\left(u^x\right)$ where $P(a)$ is a polynomial.

Comment: I mean $\ln^{n+1}(u)n!P\left(u^x\right)$, sorry. (It's annoying how I can't edit my comments after 5 minutes...). Anyways, that should cancel out the $\ln^{n+1}(u)$ and $n!$ terms in the integral, leaving us with $\int^1_0\frac{\operatorname{Li}_n(u)}uP\left(u^x\right)du.$

Comment: Kyky correct I thought about Leibniz rule as well but I think it would get us back to to the sum

Comment: Yo I realised I made a huge mistake, I basically ignored case for x=0 so expression is not correct.